# Error in Shiny deployment on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I got a Shiny App that works fine on my PC, but once I deploy on shinyapps.io it shows the following error on the web browser:

[image]

And the following error on the Deployment Console:

```
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Failed to parse 
C:/Users/david.jorquera/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSOqdYV/file13849671673/app.R 
; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
```

If you need the exact excel file I'm using I would happily attach it if you tell me how to do it (sorry, haven't figure that out yet).
Here is the UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

EPA <- read_excel("data/EPA.xlsx")


ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel(img(src = 'logo-escudo-rojo.jpg', height=100, 
width=150)),
            titlePanel("Dirección de Análisis Institucional"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(selectInput("facultad", h4("Seleccione Facultad o Total UDP"),
                     choices=c("Arquitectura, Arte y Diseño",
                                  "Ciencias Sociales e Historia",
                                  "Comunicación y Letras",
                                  "Derecho",
                                  "Economía y Empresa",
                                  "Educación",
                                  "Ingeniería y Ciencias", 
                                  "Medicina",
                                  "Psicología",
                                  "Salud y Odontología",
                                  "Total UDP")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Arquitectura, Arte y 
Diseño'",
             selectInput("faad", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Arquitectura",
                                       "Artes Visuales",
                                       "Diseño",
                                       "Facultad de Arquitectura, Arte y Diseño"), selected="Arquitectura")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Ciencias Sociales e Historia'",
             selectInput("fcsh", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Bachillerato en Ciencias Sociales y Humanidades",
                                       "Ciencia Política",
                                       "Historia",
                                       "Sociología",
                                       "Facultad de Ciencias Sociales e Historia"), selected="Bachillerato en Ciencias Sociales y Humanidades")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Comunicación y Letras'",
             selectInput("fcyl", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Literatura Creativa",
                                       "Periodismo",
                                       "Publicidad",
                                       "Facultad de Comunicación y Letras"))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Economía y Empresa'",
             selectInput("fee", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Ingeniería Comercial",
                                       "Ingeniería en Control de Gestión",
                                       "Contador Auditor-Contador Público 
(D)",
                                       "Facultad de Economía y Empresa"))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Educación'",
             selectInput("fed", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Pedagogía Básica",
                                       "Pedagogía Parvularia",
                                       "Pedagogía en Educación Diferencial",
                                       "Pedagogía en Inglés",
                                       "Pedagogía Media en Lenguaje y 
Comunicación",
                                       "Pedagogía Media en Historia y 
Ciencias Sociales",
                                       "Facultad de Educación"))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Ingeniería y Ciencias'",
             selectInput("fing", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Ingeniería Civil Plan Común",
                                       "Ingeniería Civil Industrial",
                                       "Ingeniería Civil en Informática y 
Telecomunicaciones",
                                       "Ingeniería Civil en Obras Civiles",
                                       "Facultad de Ingeniería y 
Ciencias"))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.facultad=='Salud y Odontología'",
             selectInput("fsyod", h4("Seleccione carrera o Total Facultad"),
                          choices=c("Enfermería",
                                       "Kinesiología",
                                       "Odontología",
                                       "Obstetricia y Neonatología",
                                       "Tecnología Médica",
                                       "Facultad de Salud y 
Odontología")))),

  mainPanel(h4("Encuesta de Primer Año"),


plotOutput("grafico1"),
br(),
br(),
plotOutput("grafico2")


)
))
```

...And here is the Server

```
server <- function(input, output) {


base <- reactive ({

base <-   if(input$facultad == "Arquitectura, Arte y Diseño") {
      filter(EPA, Carrera==input$faad)}
   else 
     if(input$facultad == "Ciencias Sociales e Historia") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera==input$fcsh)}
   else
     if(input$facultad == "Comunicación y Letras") {
   filter(EPA, Carrera==input$fcyl)}  
   else
     if(input$facultad == "Derecho") {
       filter(EPA, Carrera == "Facultad de Derecho")}
    else
   if(input$facultad == "Economía y Empresa") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == input$fee)}
   else
   if(input$facultad == "Educación") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == input$fed)}
 else
   if(input$facultad == "Ingeniería y Ciencias") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == input$fing)}
 else
   if(input$facultad == "Medicina") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == "Facultad de Medicina")}
 else
   if(input$facultad == "Psicología") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == "Facultad de Psicología")}
 else
   if(input$facultad == "Salud y Odontología") {
     filter(EPA, Carrera == input$fsyod)}


  }) 


  output$grafico1 <- renderPlot({

datos <- base()

    ggplot(datos, aes(Año, EPA_T_2, label=paste(round(EPA_T_2*100, 0), "%", 
sep="")))  + 
      geom_col(aes(y = EPA_T_2)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name = "Cohorte de Ingreso", 
                         breaks = seq(min(datos[[4]]), max(datos[[4]]), 1)) 
+
      scale_y_continuous(name = "% de Estudiantes encuestados", labels = 
scales::percent) +
      geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=5) +
      ggtitle("Tasa de Respuesta Encuesta de Primer Año") + 
theme(plot.title=
           element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=20, hjust=0.5))

  })



output$grafico2 <- renderPlot({

datos <- base()

ggplot(datos, aes(Año, EPA_T_1_OK, label=EPA_T_1_OK)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = EPA_T_1_OK)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Cohorte de Ingreso", 
                     breaks = seq(min(datos[[4]]), max(datos[[4]]), 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "N° de Estudiantes encuestados", breaks = 
seq(min(0), max(datos[[6]]+10), 20)) +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=5) +
  ggtitle("Número de Estudiantes Encuestados") + theme(plot.title=
          element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=20, hjust=0.5))


})  

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've seen this question presented before and one solution was related to replacing `library()` for `require()`, but this has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Smells like an encoding issue. See https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/285

Comment: its you;re library issue, I had the same with `Rcpp` mix up. So I re-installed R and Shiny Server and only installed packages as superuser

Comment: It's not any of the above. I've tried different encodings and tried on a different computer with superuser profile. The example app on the shinyapps guide (with old faithful data) uploads fine, so I don't know what could be it!
I'm losing it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of trying different solutions, it turns out IT WAS a problem related to encoding. Te solution however wasn't on trying enconding specifications inside the code (I tried saving with UTF-8 my app and my database, using `enc2utf8()` and other related functions; revisiting similar issues on this webpage, etc). 
Finally, it turns out that the Server was making calls to values inside the database that were full of special characters (mostly ñ and accent marks). So the solution was to replace those calls for calls on values instead of strings. I only wish someone would told me that sooner! but anyway, live and learn.

Comment: Awesome! I was so frustrated. My issue was that I was using an accent in the `expression()` function. What I did was replacing this with the `latex2exp::TeX()` function which recieved a string. Also, I was using inside variables In the output and input  such as `output$gráfica` and it worked by replacing `output$grafica` or `output$\`gráfica\``

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with a same issue for a few weeks ago and whenever I searched for a solution, this question you made here appeared. I finally was able to deploy my shinny app by writing the variables names between '' The problem was that my shinny couldn't find variables such us `GÉNERO` or `DÍA` when trying to deploy it, so I started to put those between backticks like `` `DÍA` `` and `` `GÉNERO` `` (after re writing it from 0).
I wanted to let this workaround written somewhere and this question seems to be the best place. Regards from Argentina!

Comment: Hola Joaquín, gracias por la respuesta. La verdad es que después de años de experiencia, ahora nunca llamaría a las variables con tildes o caracteres especiales. Esas cosas pueden ir en las etiquetas, que aguantan todo, pero para variables y objetos del sistema, es mejor nombres alfanuméricos sencillos (de todas formas, si tengo que hacerlo, las encierro en el backquote "`" y ya está). También miro el código de mi pregunta y me horroriza, pero creo que es mejor dejarla porque sé que no soy el único que se ha encontrado con este problema. Saludos from Chile!